# Not letting the character move out of the window

Tags: python, pygame

I tried using this kind of code:

```
if circleX - 16 == 0:
    circleX = 16
elif circleY - 16 == 0:
    circleY = 16
elif circleY + 16 == 500:
    circleY = 484
elif circleX + 16 == 500:
    circleX = 484
elif circleY - 16 == 0 and circleX - 16 == 0:
    circleY = 16
    circleX = 16
elif circleY + 16 == 500 and circleX + 16 == 500:
    circleX = 484
    circleY = 484
elif circleY + 16 == 500 and circleX - 16 == 0:
    circleY = 484
    circleX = 16
elif circleY - 16 == 0 and circleX + 16 == 500:
    circleX = 484
    circleY = 16
```

But it doesn't seem to work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid sameness relation comparison `==` for boundary. I use `<=` or `>=` for compare boundary.

I do not know about your code and context, but I suppose `circleX`, `circleY` has been changed on other method.

If it change variables as like `circleX += 20`, it can be passed all if-condition. or if it was called too fast by some events on thread environment, we can not trust the value of `circleX`.

I recommend to compare as following:

```py
if circleX - 16 <= 0:  # Left border
    circleX = 16
elif circleY - 16 <= 0:  # Top
    circleY = 16
elif circleY + 16 >= 500:  # Bottom
    circleY = 484
elif circleX + 16 >= 500:  # Right
    circleX = 484
elif circleY - 16 <= 0 and circleX - 16 <= 0:  # Top Left corner
    circleY = 16
    circleX = 16
elif circleY + 16 >= 500 and circleX + 16 >= 500:  # Bottom right
    circleX = 484
    circleY = 484
elif circleY + 16 >= 500 and circleX - 16 <= 0:  # Bottom left
    circleY = 484
    circleX = 16
elif circleY - 16 <= 0 and circleX + 16 >= 500:  # Top right
    circleX = 484
    circleY = 16
```

and it can be shorten by using less if condition:

```py
if circleX - 16 <= 0:      # Left border
    circleX = 16
    if circleY - 16 <= 0:  # Top Left corner
        circleY = 16
elif circleY - 16 <= 0:      # Top
    circleY = 16
    if circleX + 16 >= 500:  # Top right
        circleX = 484
elif circleY + 16 >= 500:  # Bottom
    circleY = 484
    if circleX - 16 <= 0:  # Bottom left
        circleX = 16
elif circleX + 16 >= 500:    # Right
    circleX = 484
    if circleY + 16 >= 500:  # Bottom right
        circleY = 484
```

BUT, more short code in my personal favorite is:

```py
circleX = min(max(16, circleX), 484)
circleY = min(max(16, circleY), 484)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object to limit the a circle to the bounds of the window In the following `window` is the display *Surface* :

```py
radius = 16
clampRect = window.get_rect().inflate(-radius*2, -radius*2)
circleX = max(clampRect.left, min(clampRect.right, circleX))
circleY = max(clampRect.top, min(clampRect.bottom, circleY))
```

Explanation:

[`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) generates a `pygame.Rect` with the size oft the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) which is associated to the display. [`inflate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) generates a new rectangle with the size changed by the diameter oft the circle, where the rectangle remains centered around its current center.
In the following, `min` and `max` are used to clamp the center of the circle in the area defined by the rectangle.